# How to pass reference of specific location in a vector to a pointer?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that I am making use of that takes in a pointer to a location in a vector and is going to iterate it. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void funcy(int *n, double *x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
    }  // next i
}  // funcy()

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    std::vector<double> x = {1, 2, 3};
    funcy(&n, &*x.begin());  // I can pass a pointer to the beginning of the vector

    int m = 2;

    // But how do I pass a pointer to position i in the vector?
    funcy(&m, &*x.at(1));  // why isn't this working?
    // Expecting {2 3} as output

    return 0;
}
```

How can I pass a pointer to a specific location in the vector that is not `begin()` or `end()` of the vector?

Comment: `at` doesn't return a pointer, it returns a reference.  You don't need the `*`.

Comment: Pop quiz: how does your `funcy` will know that there are only 2, and not 3, values in the vector when you do this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik come on, one bug at a time.  You're ruining the fun!

Comment: @MarkRansom so my question should ask about reference not pointers?

Comment: No, you asked the right question because your function takes a pointer.  Whether that was the best way to write it is a different question.  There's a reason all the standard algorithms take a pair of iterators as parameters.

Comment: @MarkRansom I modified the question statement. If you think this is worse, I can change it back.

Comment: I thought the question was plenty clear enough the way you first asked it, but it's your question - do with it as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can just use the []-operator for vectors, you can write `funcy(&m, &x[1]);`.

If you want to use `at()`, you can write `funcy(&m, &x.at(1));`.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are accessed using a special object called an iterator instead of references. See: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-iterators/